# Java: Carriage returns populating a var in js code?

Tags: java, javascript

I am not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to find a front-end solution to this situation:

I am setting a JavaScript variable to a dynamic tag, populated by backend Java code:

```
var myString = '@myDynamicContent@';
```

However, there are some situations, in which the content from the output contains a carriage return; which breaks the code:

```
var mystring = '<div>
                Carriage Return happened above and below.
                </div>';
```

Is there anyway I can resolve this problem on the front-end? Or is it too late in the script to do something about it, because the dynamic tag will run before any JavaScript runs (thus the script is broken by that point)?

Comment: Yes, it it is too late. You will need to handle this serverside in your dynamic tag. (Please give us more information about that Java code)

Comment: @Bergi could you not just strip the carriage returns from `myString`? For example `myString.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');`

Comment: Here's an idea: If I populate a JS comment /* @myDynamicContent */ - would I be able to read that content with JS?

Comment: @brandtrock — No. It is a comment. It is for humans, not software.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts — No. There are no new lines in the JavaScript string. There is no JavaScript string. There is a JavaScript syntax error.

Comment: Thanks everyone; we'll have to go with a Java fix beforehand - which requires a release (vs. a quick fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure my JS could be cleaned up (just thought this was a fun problem), but you could search out the comment in the JS.

Lets say your JS looks like this (noticed I added a tag to the comment so we know we're going after the correct one, and there is a div to just for testing):

```
<script id="testScript">
/*<captureMe><div>
  Carriage Return happened above and below.
  </div>
*/
var foo = 'bar';
</script>
<div id='test'>What do I see:</div>
```

Just use this to grab the comment:

```
var something = $("#testScript").html();
var newSomething = '';
newSomething = something.substr(something.indexOf("/*<captureMe>")+13);
newSomething = newSomething.substr(0, newSomething.indexOf("*/"));
$('#test').append('<br>'+newSomething);  // just proving we captured the output, will not render returns or newline as expected by HTML
```

Technically, it works :), scripting-scripting...

Charbs

Comment: I should note: I assumed you could print your dynamic content into a comments field... and that I used some jQuery (kind of goes without saying these days)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript supports strings that can span multiple lines by putting a backslash (`\`) at the end of the line, for example:

```
var myString = 'foo\
bar';
```

So you should be able to do a Java replace when you write in your server-side variable:

```
var myString = '@myDynamicContent.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n")@';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `\n` and/or `\r` with `\\n` and/or `\\r` respectively ... but it has to be done in the server-side language (in your case Java); it can't be done in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Charbs' answer, you could avoid the JavaScript comments if you give your script tag a different mime type, so the browser won't try to evaluate it as JavaScript:

```
<script id="testScript" type="text/notjs" style="display:none">@myDynamicContent@</script>
```

And then just grab it like this (using jQuery):

```
var myString = $('#testScript').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're doing token replacement instead of using a template engine. If you like token replacement you might [Snippetory](http://www.jproggy.org/snippetory) too, as it creates similar code. However it has a number of additional features. Using

`var myString = '{v:myDynamicContent enc="string"}'`

would create

```
var mystring = '<div>\r\n          Carriage Return happened above and below.\r\n                </div>'
```

And thus solve your problem. But you would have to change your code behind, too.